# Portable Stream writer c#

Tags: c#, portability, streamwriter

I'm currently making an app that needs to print out to a text file, I'm having trouble making it portable below is what I have so far

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream((@"|DataDirectory|\print" + fileName + ".txt"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                    write.write("HelloWorld"
            }
```

The error comes on the first line saying im using an invalid character, I'm assuming that is because of the |DataDirectory| but other than that I don't know how I'd be able to use it on a user's machine?

Edit: I no longer have the project to check but @leppie's comment sounds like the issue with my code. The marked answer worked as an alternative

Comment: `|DataDirectory|` is only available in web apps IIRC.

Comment: `|` is a reserved character for file/folder names according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're developing a desktop app, try with this:

```
string dir = Path.GetDirectory(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string filename = Path.Combine(dir, "print", filename + ".txt");
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename,....);
```

Comment: Actually, you want `Application.StartupPath`.

Comment: Tried leppie's first as it's smaller and works perfectly
Thanks anyway though

Answer (score 2):

Revise your first line to the following:

```
var fs=new FileStream(
       string.Format(@"{0}\print\{1}.txt",
       Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
       filename),FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write);
```

Comment: This saves it to appdata\Roaming?

Comment: yup :) and it's "cross windows os" too.
I wonder how did you create your "print" folder in appdata without it..